# Enable GPIO wakeup in Embedded Linux

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, interrupt, gpio

I'm trying to enable wakeup event for GPIO on embedded Linux, after searching for a while I figured how to do it, but when I try this:

```
echo enabled > /sys/class/gpio/gpio<n>/power/wakeup
```

I get

```
write error: Invalid argument
```

Does this mean that it's not supported by the hardware ? or do I need to enable something in the kernel ?

Edit:

Just for the record, sysfs GPIO is enabled and working fine, I can read/write the GPIO values, but I can't seem to be able to enable the wakeup event, I've been reading the kernel [documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio.txt) and it says:

> "Inputs can often be used as IRQ signals, often edge triggered but
>   sometimes level triggered. **Such IRQs may be configurable as system
>   wakeup events**, to wake the  system from a low power state."

So I'm wondering, do I need to configure wakeup events for GPIO in the kernel ? and if the hardware doesn't support it, why do I have a wakeup file under **sysfs/class/gpio/gpio#/power/wakeup** ?

Comment: That's probably quite hardware-dependent.  What hardware are you using?

Comment: OLinuxino board iMX233 ARM926J processor

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your GPIO driver, which might specific for your board, handles the wakeup feature.

Comment: Any hints on what I should look for ?

Comment: Do `lsmod` and find what GPIO module you are using. GPIO drivers are located into [`drivers/gpio`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.4.4/drivers/gpio/) within the kernel source.

Comment: If you can read/write the GPIO values that means the right driver is loaded but you have to check into this driver's source code if the wakeup feature is supported.